# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" while saving CNN Model

Tags: python, python-3.7

I try to save the CNN model and weight into json format, but I got some issue here that I didn't know

```
#save model and weight
#model to json files
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model/model_json_sgd001.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
#weight to h5 file
model.save_weights("model/model_1_sgd001.h5")

print("Model dan Bobot telah disimpan")
```

the error says

```
> FileNotFoundError                         
> Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-d1dce1f405b9> in <module>
>       2 #model to json files
>       3 model_json = model.to_json()
> ----> 4 with open("model/model_json_sgd001.json", "w") as json_file:
>       5     json_file.write(model_json)
>       6 #weight to h5 file
> 
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'model/model_json_sgd001.json'
```

so I just need to make a file `model_json_sgd001.json`?

Comment: Do you have the directory `model` created?

Comment: No, i dont have the model directory, so i just need to make the directory and link the path to the code?

Comment: You're trying to write to the path `model/model_json_sgd001.json`, which means the file named `model_json_sgd001.json` in the directory `model`. You need to have that directory there otherwise you'll get an error. `open()` does not create directories for you, only files.

Comment: Yeap, it solved, thanks man i appreciate your help a lot